# Unable to center bytefield on the page

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, bytefield

I am trying to center a couple of bytefields on the page. The problem I'm encountering is that bytefield is left justified, when I declare bitwidth = \textwidth/32 it appears centered but is not. If I set bitwidth = 0.75\textwidth/16 then it lives on the left 3/4 of the page. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
   \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.jpg,.eps,.svg}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in,bottom=1in,top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{fontspec}
   \setmainfont{calibri}
\newlength{\charht}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\charht}{\fontcharht\font`X}}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\newcommand{\baselinealign}[1]{%
  \centering
  \strut\small#1%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{x0000 Interrupt Status Register}
\begin{bytefield}[bitformatting = {\small},%
                  bitwidth={ 0.75\textwidth/16},%
                  bitheight = {\charht*2}]{16}
\bitheader[endianness=big, lsb=16]{16-31}\\
\bitbox{16}{NODEINT} & \\
\\
\bitheader[endianness = big]{0-15}\\
\bitbox{14}{RSV} & \bitbox{1}{FBA} & \bitbox{1}{TOF} & \\
\end{bytefield}
\label{tab:x0000}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Is there a method to center bytefield that I've missed in the documentation?

As an aside, I'm generating the bytefield format via a script, so any ideal solution would be consistent/simple.

Comment: welcome to tex.se!. please provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...} and ending with `\end{document}` , called minimal working example (mwe), which we can copy and test it.  probably the solution for your problem is add `\centering` after `\begin{table}`, however now i cant test this (due to lack of minimal wme).

Comment: That was the solution Zarko, between writing out the document and scripting the text I lost \centering after \begin{table}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only need add `\centering` after `begin{table}`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
   \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.jpg,.eps,.svg}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage[showframe,
            margin=0.7in,bottom=1in,top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{fontspec}
   \setmainfont{calibri}
\newlength{\charht}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\charht}{\fontcharht\font`X}}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\newcommand{\baselinealign}[1]{%
  \centering
  \strut\small#1%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering % <----
\caption{x0000 Interrupt Status Register}
\begin{bytefield}[bitformatting = {\small},%
                  bitwidth={ 0.75\textwidth/16},%
                  bitheight = {\charht*2}]{16}
\bitheader[endianness=big, lsb=16]{16-31}\\
\bitbox{16}{NODEINT} & \\
\\
\bitheader[endianness = big]{0-15}\\
\bitbox{14}{RSV} & \bitbox{1}{FBA} & \bitbox{1}{TOF} & \\
\end{bytefield}
\label{tab:x0000}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]